# C++ Custom List Deleting Nodes

Tags: c++

I am not sure whether I should start a new thread or not but as editing my previous question would involve a lot of rearranging of code I think a new one is best.

```
template <class T>
class node {
public:
    T value;
    node<T> *next;
    node<T> *previous;  
};

template <class T>
class my_list {
public:
    node<T> *first;
    node<T> *last;
    my_list(){
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    ~my_list(){
    }
    void push_back(T val);
    void push_front(T val);
    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();
    T front();
    T back();
};
```

Above is the class layout. Below is the pop_back() method which should remove the last node in the list. I cannot get it to work. It runs but doesn't seem to reassign last node as when I call the T back() function it returns a random value.

```
template <class T>
void my_list<T>::pop_back(){
    node<T> oldlast = *this->last;
    node<T> newlast = *oldlast.previous;
    cout << newlast.value << endl;
    newlast.next = NULL;
    this->last = this->last->previous;
}  


template <class T>
void my_list<T>::push_back(T val){
    if (this->first == NULL) {
    node<T> newnode;
    newnode.value = val;
    newnode.next = NULL;
    newnode.previous = NULL;
    this->first = &newnode;
    this->last = &newnode;
} else {
    node<T> current = *this->last;
    node<T> newnode;
    newnode.value = val;
    newnode.previous = &current;
    newnode.next = NULL;
    current.next = &newnode;
    this->last = &newnode;
}
}

template <class T>
void my_list<T>::push_front(T val){
if (this->first == NULL) {
    node<T> newnode;
    newnode.value = val;
    newnode.next = NULL;
    newnode.previous = NULL;
    this->first = &newnode;
    this->last = &newnode;
} else {
    node<T> current = *this->first;
    node<T> newnode;
    newnode.value = val;
    newnode.previous = NULL;
    newnode.next = &current;
    current.previous = &newnode;
    this->first = &newnode;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are making local `node<T>` variables and assigning pointers to them. When the functions end, those local variables go out of scope and your pointers are no longer valid. In the case of `pop_back`, you make copies of the last two elements in the list with the lines

```
node<T> oldlast = *this->last;
node<T> newlast = *oldlast.previous;
```

So when you modify `newlast`'s next pointer with the line

```
newlast.next = NULL;
```

You are actually modifying the *copy*, not the actual element. So instead of copying the object its self, you should be copying the pointer to the object, and then change `.` to `->` as needed:

```
template <class T>
void my_list<T>::pop_back(){
    node<T> *oldlast = last;
    node<T> *newlast = oldlast->previous;
    cout << newlast->value << endl;
    newlast->next = NULL;
    last = newlast;
    delete oldlast;
}
```

---

For `push_back` and `push_front`, `newnode` is a local variable and so is destroyed when the function ends.  Instead, you have to dynamically allocate it with `new` (Even better would be to use a smart pointer such as [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) but I'm assuming this is for a course where you probably cannot use that).  You should create `newnode` like this

```
node<T>* newnode = new node<T>;
```

Since `newnode` is a pointer, you'll have to again change all the `.` to `->`.  Also, since you're allocating this node with `new`, you have to deallocate it with `delete` to avoid a memory leak.  So in your `pop_back` function you have to delete the element you're removing from the list (the `delete oldlast;` line).

Comment: Thanks for that. When I do that, I get an error ' error: request for member ‘previous’ in ‘oldlast’, which is of pointer type ‘node<int>*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)' for the line node<T> *newlast = oldlast.previous;

Comment: @Vuzuggu I forgot to change the `.` to a `->` in the second line of the function.

Comment: It compiled but still get segmentation fault. Im completely lost at this stage :/

Comment: @Vuzuggu you should probably check if the list is empty or if it has only one element in `pop_back()`. Also the problem might be with your `push_back` or `push_front` functions as well, post the code for those.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include push_back and push_front fuctions. Once I have the pop_back() function working I will implement the check to see if it has only one element or is empty

Comment: I deleted my own answer as I myself got confused with the use of *this->last. This is actually the same as *(this->last) when I thought it corresponded to (*this)->last which would be incorrect. Suggestion: Use parentheses for clarity! I think David is on the right track, so +1.